# How to use DNS to set a subfolder of one domain to redirect to another domain

Tags: domains, dns, multiple-domains

I have a situation where I need a subfolder, in one domain, to redirect to a second domain, so http://domain1.com/domain2/  would redirect to http://domain2.com.

I need the root folder of domain1.com to remain as it is, just the subfolder needs to redirect.

It needs to be this way because I need to access PHP and font files on domain 2, without violating cross-domain security. Is there a way to do this using DNS?

I only found instructions on doing this using subdomain, which I believe won't work for cross-domain PHP access.

Comment: This will probably have to be some sort of .htaccess redirect. DNS doesn't do directories. It knows nothing of file systems.

Comment: DNS isn't a protocol designed for that. What you are trying to achieve is not possible with DNS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This definitely can't be done with DNS.

I think the real question you want to solve is *"How do I allow cross-domain PHP and fonts?"*

---

To enable cross-domain PHP and font files (this is probably all you need) you would add the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header to **domain2's configuration**, like so

**Apache:**

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://domain1.com"
```

**Nginx:**

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://domain1.com";
```

If you do it this way you don't need http:/domain1/domain2 at all, get rid of it as it's confusing.

---

If you actually want to permanently redirect domain1/subfolder > domain2 then it's a simple change in **domain1's configuration** like this.

**Apache:**

```
Redirect 301 /subfolder http://domain2.com
```

**Nginx:**

```
location /subfolder {
            return 301 http://domain2.com;
            }
```

Note that for both sets of answers, the Nginx directives need to be inside your server {...} blocks, and the Apache rules can go in your virtualhost config or in .htaccess (do yourself a favor and skip .htaccess if you can, put everything in your config/virtualhost for performance reasons). The Apache rules rely on mod_rewrite and mod_headers, which must be enabled.

Comment: Wow, thank you!  You're right, I don't really care about the subfolders, I just didn't realize there was a simple way to allow cross-domain access like that.  That's all I really needed :-)  I would upvote your answer but I don't have privileges yet.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done via DNS.  You either need to do it at the web server level (.htacess apache / rewrite rules IIS), or via a script that runs ASP.net, PHP, Perl etc.  Essentially you need to change the response header to moved, and dns cannot do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can only do this from DNS with a subdomain, not with subfolders. For subfolders, you need to do a proxy-pass - here's how it's done in Apache (version 2.4 and above):

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /subfolder/ http://otherdomain.com/
ProxyPassReverse /subfolder/ http://otherdomain.com/
<Location /subfolder/>
    ProxyHTMLEnable On
    ProxyHTMLURLMap / /subfolder/
</Location>
```

You couls also use `http://otherdomain.com:8080` if your second host serves the content on port 8080. Also, you need to have `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_html` enabled in your Apache server for this to work. The `mod_proxy_html` module is used to rewrite the links to your static resources (images, css, javascript etc.) so that if you have relative links in the response from *otherdomain.com*, for example, they would be loaded properly.

For older versions that don't have `mod_proxy_html`, you can try and use `mod_substitute` and some regular expressions magic to achieve the same result.